# Ensure cache manifest is not cached by browser using IIS

Tags: html, iis

I'm going to be adding a cache manifest to my web app. However, I will be adding the app to IIS, and I'm unsure about how to ensure "that the cache manifest file is not cacheable by HTTP semantics" - ref http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Anyone know how to ensure a file with the .appcache extension never gets cached by the browser or intermediary proxies?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the IIS Manager,

Then choose the site settings (IS) for Output Caching. add a rule for .appcache

Go to Actions, and Add..

[image]